# Generating ctags for libc in mac

Tags: macos, vim, ctags, libc

I'm trying to use the tags of the libc library on a mac (Mountain Lion) through vim. I've generated tags from `*.c` files in `/usr/include` (`ctags -R /usr/include/*.h`). I've set `tags` to include the generated tags file (`set tags+=tags`). But, if I try to go to a tag on a function like `fseek()` it will say "no tags found". How can I solve this?

edit:

I've tried doing `ctags /usr/lib/libc.dylib`, and now it results in an error saying the file is not sorted. :(

Comment: Could you be more precise: exact commands issued in Vim, exact error messages?

Comment: Can you assume I haven't done anything, and list out the steps that I should follow to look at libc function definitions from my C program?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this line to generate a usable `tags` file:

```
ctags -R --c++-kinds=+p --fields=+iaS --extra=+q /usr/include
```

Once it's done, `:tag fseek` should work, as well as `<C-]>` on an `fseek` call.

Be sure to read `:h tags` and `:h ctags` carefully.

Comment: Thanks! That just worked. Have so much to learn as a C noob, and these sort of things help easing the learning curve.